# goofy webkit bug - refreshing versus clicking changes element placement

Tags: css, list, webkit, html-lists

Check out [the gallery i'm building](http://www.dubiousgallery.com) on a webkit browser..

notice that the words on the top right - **available, sold, contact** - which are part of a `<ul>`, are listed *vertically*.. even though on Firefox, they are listed *horizontally* because of `ul {list-style-type: none;}` and `li {float: left;}`.

Click "**available**", and notice that they *neatly align horizontally*. Use the back button or click "**dubious**" in the top-left corner and they stay in that neat horizontal alignment on the first page. Then **refresh your browser**, and it becomes vertical again.

```
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
}

.menu li {
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    font-size: 20pt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The font in the menu titles used with font-face definition causes this. 
A related topic: [Accurate width of element when using font-face in Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701892/accurate-width-of-element-when-using-font-face-in-chromium) 
You may try "display:inline-block" for li's instead of "float: left;"

And why don't you use png images for menu titles?

Comment: I tried `display:inline-block` and `display:inline`.. neither of them worked.. and it caused it to fail on firefox as well. That post on the fonts is very interesting though. Given the complexity of having to figure out how to use that Google Webfont Loader to make it all work.. I think I will take your advice for now and just make .pngs when I have settled on names.

I didn't like having to do that because I would prefer that things be editable and scalable.. but oh well. Kinks are kinks